# How to use RETS Connector to Download a CSV file

Tags: rets, mls

I have a RETS feed and I am using RETS Connnector http://www.retsconnector.com/Home/ConnectorDownload

Does anyone know how to set your search criteria to dump all the data along with img urls

Answer (score 0):

Every search has options for downloading media in the media tab. You can select whether or not you want to download all media or just the default images of the listings your query returns.